# Absoluteness of "$\kappa$-homogeneously Suslin" for sets of reals

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, large-cardinals

What is known about the absoluteness, or lack thereof, of the notion of "$\kappa$-homogeneously Suslin" for sets of reals?

For example, if $A$ is $\kappa$-homogeneously Suslin and $\lambda > \kappa$ is inaccessible, does $V_\lambda \vDash {}$"$A$ is $\kappa$-homogeneously Suslin"?

The corresponding absoluteness is true for "$\kappa$-universally Baire," so if there are some Woodin cardinals around $\kappa$ then one can prove an approximation to this absoluteness for "$\kappa$-homogeneously Suslin."  But such an argument made me wonder if some absoluteness property for "$\kappa$-homogeneously Suslin" might be provable outright.

Comment: Oops, one has to add the condition that there is a measurable cardinal $\mu$ with $\kappa \le \mu < \lambda$ (we might as well assume that $\kappa$ itself is measurable) or else it is obviously false.  (Maybe that's what the down-vote was for?)